# ASP.NET MVC: Language Globalization - Required Error Message is Always in English

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resources, globalization, multilingual

I am learning how to do globalization, and everything is working well, except for one thing.  I have some required fields, and their error message is always in English. Everything else will swap languages, and maintain the correct language after a post-back, but that dang error message is English no matter what.  I really hope you can help me spot my error!

**Model:**

```
namespace xxxx.Models
{
    public class PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage : Page
    {

        public Boolean Page1Complete { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.CustomerSatisfactionSurvey), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Page1Question1Required")]
        public int? LikelyToReturn { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.CustomerSatisfactionSurvey), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Page1Question2Required")]
        public int? RecomendToFriend { get; set; }
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div><input type="submit" id="page1-submit" name="page1-submit" value="continue" class="btn green2"></div>
<div>@Html.ValidationSummary()</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PatientSatisfactionSurvey(string ApptID, string LanguageCode)
    {

        PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage pss = new PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage();

        // Create list of available language options
        pss.LanguageOptions = new List<string> { "en", "es", "fr" };

        // Validate and set the language code
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LanguageCode))
        {
            // Check the incoming Language Code (LanguageCode) against the list off approved options
            if (pss.LanguageOptions.Contains(LanguageCode))
            {
                // Set the culture based on the language code
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageCode);
                pss.LanguageCode = LanguageCode;
            }
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PatientSatisfactionSurvey([Bind]PatientSatisfactionSurveyPage pss, string ApptID)
    {

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(pss.LanguageCode);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            pss.Page1Complete = true;
        }

        return View(pss);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set the culture in the Gobal.asax.cs file's Application_BeginRequest() with a cookie.  I also modified the controller to set the cookie

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        HttpCookie LanguageCookie = Request.Cookies["LanguageCode"];
        if (LanguageCookie != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(LanguageCookie.Value);
        }
    }
```